# How to extract content present in Manifest file in java?

Tags: java, manifest.mf

I want to read contents present inside manifest file in java. Is there any library to do so ?

Manifest file content look like:

```
Pay date,Data_feed_name
31/03/18,PS_IND_ALLSEC_100_20180331_1.PDF
31/03/18,PS_IND_ALLSEC_101_20180331_1.PDF
31/03/18,PS_IND_ALLSEC_102_20180331_1.PDF
31/03/18,PS_IND_ALLSEC_103_20180331_1.PDF
```

Comment: It seems that the Manifest file is a CSV file, but the 1st line is in wrong format. And there are many popular libraries (e.g. Common CSV or OpenCSV) can parse such file.

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18899123/what-is-the-proper-way-to-parse-the-entries-of-a-manifest-mf-file-in-jar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the proper way to parse the entries of a manifest.mf file in jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18899123/what-is-the-proper-way-to-parse-the-entries-of-a-manifest-mf-file-in-jar)

Comment: That is certainly not a `manifest.mf` file. A manifest file contains lines of `name: value` pairs. If your `META-INF/manifest.mf` file looks like that, then it's corrupt, and you need to fix your build system.

Comment: @Andreas I would upvote an Answer made of your Comment.

Comment: @BasilBourque It's not an answer. We don't know what OP wants. I'm just pointing out an issue with what's written in the question. Does OP want to know how to: 1) Read a manifest file? 2) Read a CSV file? It cannot be both at the same time, so we need OP to clarify, and we're still waiting on OP.

Comment: @Andreas Fair enough, good point.